# Can not Open Table or Store in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I using Sql Server 2012, when i open table or store procedure is show dialog **"The File exits.(mscorlib)"**, it cant open anything.

It happened today. Anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing `(Sql files with the type .sql)` your temp data  .
 To get the path of your Temp folder,In the command prompt type ECHO %Temp%.